Triggering Stripe Connect express onboarding modal again for users to complete their identity verification process
I am using Stripe Express in our onboarding process. Is there a way to trigger the stripe-hosted modal again and show where the user left off if a user has not yet verified?

You can create a new Account Link

of type=account_onboarding to let users complete the outstanding requirements, or
of type=account_update to modify the already provided fields.

